# how to call javascript function of one jsp from another jsp function

Tags: javascript

I have hello() javascript fuction in file1.jsp. I want to call hello() by file2.jsp.
file1.jsp has

```
<html>
<script>
function hello()
{
...
}
</script>
</html>
```

I want to call this hello() function from file2.jsp

Answer (score 3):

Perform the steps below:

Move the script in page1.jsp file to a new JavaScript file e.g. main.js file and place the file in new folder e.g. js inside your WebContent folder.

Link main.js in page1.jsp file by putting below link in the  section:

/js/main.js">
Do the same in page2.jsp file.

This way, same javascript code will be available for use in both page1.jsp and page2.jsp files.

Comment: Yes, it's always a good idea to separate your javascript code from your markup.